# Ruby - Sort array of arrays based on sum and object type

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

I have an array of arrays, of varying object types and I wish to extract the arrays from the array of arrays if the sum of the non integers multiplied by two is greater than or equal to the sum of the entire array. For example:

```
elements = [
  [1, 2, "3", "4"],
  [1, "2", "3", 5],
  ["1", 2, 3, "4.0"],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, "5"],
  [1, 2, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
]

expected output:

elements = [
  [1, 2, "3", "4"],
  ["1", 2, 3, "4.0"],
  [1, 2, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
]
```

As the sum of the strings and floats are greater than or equal to the sum of integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

- [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#select-method) to extract the arrays based on a condition
- [`Enumerable#grep_v`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#grep_v-method) to extract non-integers
- [`Array#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#sum-method) to calculate the sums (using `to_f` for conversion)

```
elements.select do |ary|
  ary.grep_v(Integer).sum(&:to_f) * 2 >= ary.sum(&:to_f)
end
#=> [[1, 2, "3", "4"], ["1", 2, 3, "4.0"], [1, 2, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]]
```

You could also pass the `to_f`-call to `grep_v`, i.e. `ary.grep_v(Integer, &:to_f).sum` but I prefer to have identical `sum`-calls on both sides.

Comment: Considering that `ary.grep_v(Integer).sum(&:to_f) = ary.sum(&:to_f) - ary.grep(Integer).sum`, it may be more efficient (depending in part on the proportion of values that are integers) to write `2 * ary.grep(Integer).sum <= ary.sum(&:to_f)`, though I don't think that is as clear (but it does avoid the need for the reader to answer the question, "What the heck is `grep_v`?").

Answer (score 2):

Create a lambda to multiply the called object. We need to convert strings to floats as a string can represent either integer or float.

```
multiply = -> (x) {
  x = x.to_f if x.is_a? String
  x * 2 # both lines could of course be re-written at x.to_f * 2 as engineersmnky suggests, this was a verbose way of explaining the need to convert to float
}
```

Reverse grep Integer objects, to return any other type and multiply them for cross comparison against the array mapped to floats (to handle the multiple types).

```
elements.select { |arr| arr.grep_v(Integer, &multiply).sum >= arr.map(&:to_f).reduce(:+) }
```

Comment: I think the lambda could reasonably be reduced to `->(x) {x.to_f * 2}` following ruby's duck typing principle. Right now if say `elements` contained `[[["1",2]]]` then the `grep_v` would collect the sub array then `multiply` would result in [12,12] however by adding the `to_f` message an error would be raised which seems more in line with the intent of the process. Or maybe more verbosely `->(x) { x.to_r.to_f * 2}` to handle `String`s like "1/2"

Comment: Correction to my previous comment `multiply` would result in `["1",2,"1",2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
elements.select do |a|
  ints, non_ints = a.partition { |e| e.is_a? Integer }
  non_ints.sum(&:to_f) >= ints.sum
end
  #=> [[1, 2, "3", "4"], ["1", 2, 3, "4.0"], [1, 2, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]]
```

See [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition). Note:

```
a = elements[0]
  #=> [1, 2, "3", "4"] 
ints, non_ints = a.partition { |e| e.is_a? Integer }
  #=> [[1, 2], ["3", "4"]] 

a = elements[1]
  # => [1, "2", "3", 5] 
ints, non_ints = a.partition { |e| e.is_a? Integer }
  #=> [[1, 5], ["2", "3"]]
```

and so on.